# I am trying to get all Power BI reports while this process I sent CURL request in PHP to authenticate the user but it's throwing below error response

Tags: azure-active-directory, powerbi

Please help me how to resolve this issue.

**Error Response**:

Array
(
[error] => invalid_grant
[error_description] => AADSTS65001: The user or administrator has not consented to use the application with ID '27ccc3c6-6560-461c-bf42-c0f3f756fa7a' named 'DrCloudEHR - East'. Send an interactive authorization request for this user and resource.
Trace ID: c137e449-e653-43d8-88f8-9abb8499b100
Correlation ID: 0b2f5c0d-ac09-49bc-81f3-b8b95a185186
Timestamp: 2020-11-20 06:10:03Z
[error_codes] => Array
(
[0] => 65001
)

```
[timestamp] => 2020-11-20 06:10:03Z
[trace_id] => c137e449-e653-43d8-88f8-9abb8499b100
[correlation_id] => 0b2f5c0d-ac09-49bc-81f3-b8b95a185186
[suberror] => consent_required
```

)

**CURL REQUEST code**:

```
$curlPostToken = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($curlPostToken, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => "https://login.windows.net/common/oauth2/token",
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
    CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
    CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
    CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => array(
        grant_type => 'password',
        scope => 'openid',
        prompt => 'admin_consent',
        client_secret => '~-8gGXjt~Ag7_o_N0~l9.K63Iza_FA49TR',
        resource => 'https://analysis.windows.net/powerbi/api',
        client_id => '27ccc3c6-6560-461c-bf42-c0f3f756fa7a', // Registered App ApplicationID
        username => '*********g@*******.com', // for example john.doe@yourdomain.com
        password => '**********' // Azure password for above user
    )
));

$tokenResponse = curl_exec($curlPostToken);
$tokenError = curl_error($curlPostToken); print_r($tokenError); 
curl_close($curlPostToken);    

$tokenResult = json_decode($tokenResponse, true);
```

print_r($tokenResult); exit;

Comment: Go to your registered app and click "API permissions" tab, then click "Grant admin consent for xxx". Please have a try. By the way, you can just do it with admin account.

Comment: Did you have a try ? Does it work ?

Comment: i hope you have change your pw immediately, the mistake is not gone just because you edited it out